# Change CSV delimiter to comma in PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un pequeño problema, tengo un fichero CSV con un separador `;` , el problema es que cuando trato de crear el objeto mediante:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
is not recognised as an OLE file
```

Entiendo que el problema es porque un CSV tiene que venir delimitado por coma, y no por punto y coma, he tratado de cambiarle la extensión manualmente, pero el archivo se vuelve corrupto, y tampoco me deja abrirlo con el Excel5, entonces mi duda es si se podría leer el archivo y sustituir el separador que viene por la coma.

Comment: Hey Imanol, welcome to Stackoverflow in Spanish, you have to translate this question to spanish! =)

Comment: considera modificar el título también.

Comment: ¿Has intentado con `$objReader->setDelimiter(";"); `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza [`setDelimiter`](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel_Reader/PHPExcel_Reader_CSV.html#methodsetDelimiter) para resolver tu problema:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('CSV');
$objReader->setDelimiter(';');
//resto del código...
```

Comment: Jejejejejejeje cuando cargue tu pregunta, era lo mismo que mi comentario XD

Comment: Y no entiendo el voto negativo si esto es lo que lo hace funcionar.

Comment: Se habrá equivocado @lmanol y te dio -1?

Comment: Él aún no puede votar ni a favor ni en contra =\

Comment: Cierto! Igual +1 de mi parte, creo que esto es lo correcto =\

Comment: ¡¡Gracias :D!!!